# How to manipulate chart in generated excel by asp.net, with NPOI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, npoi

I'm not sure is it possible to fix it but I have following situation:

I have some `DataTable` with some data, and I need to prepare chart which use this data. I have read that the only possibility to make dynamicaly any chart in `NPOI` is to prepare template and only fill excel's cells. But I have some **problem**:

I can have dynamicaly number of rows of data. So I need to be able to use one template to for example 4 and 7 rows. So I have idea to select more data(in template) and use only part of them but then I have situation like this:

[image]

So I need to dynamic change range of chart. Is any possibility to solve my problem?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I am having exactly the same issue @Mateusz Rogulski

Comment: @akdurmus AFAIR no, but maybe now there are some better libs for that.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change range in your chart after you populates the table. This is example for populating table for three charts:

```
public static void ExportPackingReport_NPOI(string filepath, DataTable table)
        {
            IWorkbook xwb; // Workbook
            HSSFSheet sheet; // Sheet
            HSSFChart chart_0;// chart 1
            HSSFChart chart_1;// chart 2
            HSSFChart chart_2;// chart 3
            int rowIndex = 60; //First row of table with data
            int colIndex = 0;//First column of table with data
            int rows_count = table.Rows.Count; //Count of data in table
            try
            {
                //Read file
                using (FileStream rstr = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    xwb = new HSSFWorkbook(rstr);
                    sheet = (HSSFSheet)xwb.GetSheet(xwb.GetSheetAt(0).SheetName);
                    var charts = HSSFChart.GetSheetCharts(sheet);
                    chart_0 = charts[0]; 
                    chart_1 = charts[1]; 
                    chart_2 = charts[2]; 
                    //Write file
                    using (FileStream wstr = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        //Populating file with data from Datatable
                        SetRowData_NPOI(table, xwb, rowIndex, colIndex);
                        //Overriding data ranges of charts 
                        CellRangeAddressBase chart_range_G = new CellRangeAddress(rowIndex + 1, rowIndex + rows_count, 6, 6);
                        CellRangeAddressBase chart_range_H = new CellRangeAddress(rowIndex + 1, rowIndex + rows_count, 7, 7);
                        CellRangeAddressBase chart_range_I = new CellRangeAddress(rowIndex + 1, rowIndex + rows_count, 8, 8);
                        CellRangeAddressBase chart_range_J = new CellRangeAddress(rowIndex + 1, rowIndex + rows_count, 9, 9);

                        //Apply new ranges of charts 
                        chart_0.Series[0].SetValuesCellRange(chart_range_G);
                        chart_0.Series[1].SetValuesCellRange(chart_range_J);

                        chart_1.Series[0].SetValuesCellRange(chart_range_H);
                        chart_1.Series[1].SetValuesCellRange(chart_range_J);

                        chart_2.Series[0].SetValuesCellRange(chart_range_I);
                        chart_2.Series[1].SetValuesCellRange(chart_range_J);

                        xwb.Write(wstr);
                        wstr.Close();

                    }
                    rstr.Close();
                    xwb.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Hope it will help someone :)